# Database normalization for shoes online shop

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

**UPDATE**

Here's my current database diagram, for online shoes that would sell

- shoes that will have different categories(heels, wedges, sandals, heels discount, etc)
- each shoes  will have different color, different size. for each color and size,
- it will have different stock and maybe have different order type(Ready stock / Pre order)
- for each size and color, maybe it will have different price
- and each shoes with different size and color, they will(maybe) have different image rather than the generic ones

[image]

am i doing it correctly? what should i do to improve this database? i really really appreciate any feedback/input/critics

**END UPDATE**

im newbie in database design and confused with database design for an online shop(MySQL database)

Say that the online shop will sell shoes with different color, size, different stock and price for each color and size.

i came up with these tables:

**generic_shoes**

```
id
name
category_id
details
image
```

**colors**

```
id
color
```

**sizes**

```
id
size
size_details
```

**specific_shoes**

```
id
generic_shoes_id //references to generic_shoes
name             // if the owner wants to make another name, if not then use generic_shoes' name
order_type       //ready stock or pre order
```

then i come up with pivot colors_shoes and sizes_shoes with many to many rel:
**colors_specific_shoes**

```
id
color_id
specific_shoes_id
```

**sizes_specific_shoes**

```
id
size_id
specific_shoes_id
```

then im thinking that diff color and size will have diff stock and maybe different price, so i come up with:

**shoes_product_details**

```
id                //will be used in the orders table
colors_shoes_id   //reference to pivot colors_shoes
sizes_shoes_id    //reference to pivot sizes_shoes
specific_shoes_id //reference to specific_shoes
stock             //each color and size will have diff stock
price             //each color and size maybe will have diff price
weight            //each size will have different weight
```

i tought these tables would do just fine, but then im thinking that, should i use this table instead?

**remove** :

1. sizes_specific_shoes
2. colors_specific_shoes

and just use the color id and size id in the specific_shoes_details table:
(in the table below, i just reference directly to colors and sizes table)

**specific_product_details table**

```
id                      //will be used in the orders table
color_id                //reference to colors table
size_id                 //reference to sizes table
specific_shoes_id       //reference to specific_shoes
stock                   //each color and size will have diff stock
price                   //each color and size maybe will have diff price
weight                  //each size will have different weight
```

i think the problem is that with the last table is -> foreign key cascade if the color/size deleted then it will also delete the specific_shoes_details row.

anyone can give me better approach? because i dont know which method should i use, the first one with color and size pivot table or the last one..

thanks

i would really appreciate any help/feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did a good job with the database design.

I would go with your last one. There is little chance that you will ever want to delete a color or size. You're not longer going to do business in size 18?

A better option to deleting would be to set the color to be inactive. Add an active column so you can turn it off, but still keep inventory.

I would also add description and/or images to specific shoes.

I believe you can also choose to not cascade on delete if that's all you're concerned about.

Comment: oh ok, "deleting would be to set the color to be inactive" , so add collumn in the specific shoes? i.e = when a specific shoes does not have any color in pivot tables, then color is inactive? hmm thats a great idea!

Comment: i cannot give bounty yet, need to wait 22 hours, ill give it after the time come

Comment: @mohur I was thinking of adding the active column to the color table, so that you can disable the whole color at a time. Or you can add the active column to specific product details. I would also name it "inventory" or something similar. So you can disable a particular color combination.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the problem, it strikes me that there is some complexity that I am not able to understand. It would occur to me that you should be able to eliminate the specific tables.

Here is the schema I suggest for your consideration.

1. colors (color_id, color_name, active, ...)
2. sizes (size_id, size_name, size_description, active, ...)
3. categories (category_id, category_name, active, ...)
4. images (image_id, image_path, active, ...)
5. order_mode (mode_id, mode_name, mode_description, ...)
6. shoes (shoe_id, color_id, size_id, category_id, image_id, mode_id, stock, price, weight, ...)

You could have another level of details if your sizes needed country coding as well. In that case, consider

1. sizes (size_id, size_name, country_id, size_description, active, ...)
2. country (country_id, country_name, active, ...)

Note that I've left an active flag on all tables so that you can use that as an indication that the specific reference element is not in use and you can use that to cascade to the shoes table.

I believe that benefit of this schema is that it is simpler and as best as I can tell it provides the same level of normalization as the one you proposed.